# Android files get damaged using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory

Tags: android

I got this strange problem when I want to save images to Android from my app. The images get damaged now Android cant use them. I cant see whats wrong in my code.

Here's my download method:

```
    public void createExternalStoragePublicPicture(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {
    // Create a path where we will place our picture in the user's
    // public pictures directory.  Note that you should be careful about
    // what you place here, since the user often manages these files.  For
    // pictures and other media owned by the application, consider
    // Context.getExternalMediaDir().

    Log.i("Download", DownloadUrl);
    Log.i("File", fileName);

    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File file = new File(path, fileName);

    try {
        // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
        path.mkdirs();

        // Very simple code to copy a picture from the application's
        // resource into the external file.  Note that this code does
        // no error checking, and assumes the picture is small (does not
        // try to copy it in chunks).  Note that if external storage is
        // not currently mounted this will silently fail.
        URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl);
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        os.write(data);
        is.close();
        os.close();

        // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
        // immediately available to the user.
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
        // not currently mounted.
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, the `is.available()` does not work as you expect. Generally you should not rely on `available()` as it is not strictly specified what value it returns.

See [InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29): "It is particularly important to realize that you must not use this method to size a container and assume that you can read the entirety of the stream [...]")

Use the common "loop"-approach:

```
int c;
while ( (c = is.read(buf)) >= 0 ) {
  os.write(buf,0,c)
}
```

This makes sure you really read *all* of the bytes from the source file.